# (Xcode and Python) error: unrecognized arguments: -NSDocumentRevisionsDebugMode

Tags: python, xcode

I'm using Xcode with a custom debugging scheme to debug my Python program.  Under "Edit Scheme", I selected Python as the executable, but when I debug the program, I see an error due to unrecognized command line arguments.

```
error: unrecognized arguments: -NSDocumentRevisionsDebugMode
```

Where is that `NSDocumentRevisionsDebugMode` argument coming from? Why is Xcode adding that to the command line argument list?

Answer (score 17):

In the "Edit Scheme" window, in the "Options" tab, uncheck "Document Versions".

[image: Screenshot of the "Edit Scheme" window showing the option to deselect.]

Comment: Does anyone know what this option actually does? Couldn't find any explanation for it