# Unable to run vapor as server into an iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, backend, vapor

I am trying to add a REST API handling function to my existing iOS App. What I am trying to achieve is to make my iOS app work as local server network. I just started to learn about Vapor.

Face a problem when I want to start the server. It throws error

`Unknown command -NSDocumentRevisionsDebugMode`

Here is my class

```
import Vapor
import Leaf

class BackendManager {
    
    var app = Application(.development)
    
    init() {
        app.http.server.configuration.hostname = "0.0.0.0"
        app.http.server.configuration.port = 8080
        
        app.views.use(.leaf)
        app.leaf.cache.isEnabled = app.environment.isRelease
        app.leaf.configuration.rootDirectory = Bundle.main.bundlePath
        app.routes.defaultMaxBodySize = "50MB"
    }
    
    func start() {
        Task(priority: .background) {
            do {
                try app.start()
            } catch {
                fatalError(String(describing: error))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how I call it

```
let server = BackendManager()
server.start()
```

Here is my configuration

[image]

What am I missing here? Thanks ...

Comment: Maybe related, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46103109/xcode-and-python-error-unrecognized-arguments-nsdocumentrevisionsdebugmode

Answer (score 3):

After followed the solution suggested in [(Xcode and Python) error: unrecognized arguments: -NSDocumentRevisionsDebugMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46103109/xcode-and-python-error-unrecognized-arguments-nsdocumentrevisionsdebugmode)

It will throw another error `-AppleLanguages`

Someone in the Discord group helped me to solve this by passing this configuration before start the server

`app.environment.arguments = [app.environment.arguments[0]]` and it is done

Hope this will help anyone affected in the future

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
I had fatalError ``Fatal error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (ConsoleKitCommands.CommandError error 0.)`` and your solution helped me.